# How to select the shortest path from a selection in Prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I am a prolog beginner, have the following code which spits out all possible paths from one given node to another. Each edge is bi-directional in nature which is something to take note of.

```
nodeLink(1,2,4).
nodeLink(1,3,10).
nodeLink(1,5,2).

nodeLink(2,1,4).
nodeLink(2,5,1).
nodeLink(2,4,6).
nodeLink(2,6,1).

nodeLink(3,1,10).
nodeLink(3,5,2).
nodeLink(3,4,1).

nodeLink(4,3,1).
nodeLink(4,5,8).
nodeLink(4,2,6).

nodeLink(5,1,2).
nodeLink(5,2,1).
nodeLink(5,3,2).
nodeLink(5,4,8).

nodeLink(6,2,1).


path([B | BRest], B, [B | BRest], Length, Length).
path([A | ARest], B, Path, CurrentLength, Length) :-
    nodeLink(A, C, X),
    \+member(C, [A | ARest]),
    NewLength is CurrentLength + X,

    path([C, A | ARest], B, Path, NewLength, Length).

all_paths(Start, End) :-
    path([Start], End, Path, 0, Length),
    reverse(Path, RevPath),
    write('Path: '),
    printPath(RevPath),
    write(' with a cost of '),
    writeln(Length),
    fail.

printPath([]).
printPath([X]) :-
    !,
    write(X).
printPath([X|Xrest]) :-
    write(X),
    write(', '),
    printPath(Xrest).
```

For example:

```
?- all_paths(6,3).
```

Prints out:

```
Path: 6, 2, 1, 3 with a cost of 15
Path: 6, 2, 1, 5, 3 with a cost of 9
Path: 6, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3 with a cost of 16
Path: 6, 2, 5, 1, 3 with a cost of 14
Path: 6, 2, 5, 3 with a cost of 4
Path: 6, 2, 5, 4, 3 with a cost of 11
Path: 6, 2, 4, 3 with a cost of 8
Path: 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3 with a cost of 27
Path: 6, 2, 4, 5, 3 with a cost of 17
false.
```

How would I go about selecting the 'shortest' path for a given pair of nodes?
Thanks

Comment: The simplest solution is to store all the paths in a list and then select the shortest. Not optimal but fast to implement and easy to understand

Comment: @CFER you may unaccept my answer. Although it provides useful concept for enumerating, it isn't the optimum solution for lowest cost path. An appropriate approach would be to use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in Prolog, you wouldn't want to use `write` and a failure driven loop to show all of the solutions. A canonical approach is to have a predicate that succeeds for each solution (as your `path/5` predicate does), and then use `findall/3` or `bagof/3` or `setof/3` to collect all of the solutions in a list. `setof/3` has the benefit of eliminating duplicates and ordering the resulting collection.

Here's a stackoverflow search on [[prolog] shortest path directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+shortest+path+directed+graph). This has been covered so many times on this site, I didn't want to just pick one of them. I didn't see one that uses `setof/3`, so here is a solution taking that approach.

I'll use your existing definition of `path/5`. Since the collection of paths is unique by design, using `setof/3` will be a small improvement over the use of `findall/3` followed by `msort/2`, which you'll find in at least one of the linked solutions. The idea here is to create a list of solutions of the form `Cost-Path`, that are ordered by `Cost`. You then need to pick the lowest cost from the list, which is the first element since they are ordered.

```
shortest_path(Start, End, ShortestPath, ShortestLength) :-
    setof(Length-Path, path([Start], End, Path, 0, Length), [ShortestLength-ShortestPath|_]).
```

If you want to then do a nice printout of your list, you can use `maplist`:

```
print_path(Cost-Path) :-
    write('Path: '),
    write(Path),
    write(' with a cost of '),
    write(Cost), nl.

print_paths(CostPaths) :-
    maplist(print_path, CostPaths).
```

Where `CostPaths` is the result of the `setof/3` performed above.

Comment: If "this has been covered so many times on this site", why don't you give a once-and-for-ever definite, generic definition?

Comment: @false, it's been covered many different ways. I'm not going to claim, at the moment, that this variation I've posted is the best of them.

Comment: @false: There are better algorithms to find the shortest path, so the solution proposed here should not be the definite solution

Comment: Is it really the purpose of SO to post over and over again the very same ad hoc solutions?

Comment: @false no it is not. But I didn't deem this to be "the very same" ad hoc solution. I didn't see one in my quick search that matched it, although some were similar. That's why I posted it. However, that doesn't mean that I wasn't thorough enough in my search. If you find a "very same" solution as the one I've posted, I'd be happy to delete this one.

Comment: Missing: What is the canonical way to put the arguments of a call/4-able edge-predicate. And so on and so forth.

Comment: And: What if there are several shortest paths? You will show only the one which is lexicographically smallest. Why that? (I just wanted to make a dupe, but not with an incorrect solution). That is, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708507/prolog-shortest-path) one.

Comment: @false yes, there could me more than one. With the above brute force method, one would need to collect all of the elements at the head of the list that had the same cost or length.